# Bitcode disabled on Carthage dependencies

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, bitcode

**Scenario**

My project (codebase shared for iOS/watchOS/tvOS ) has build settings with `ENABLE_BITCODE = YES` and takes advantage of fundamental libraries which are not yet supporting bitcode, although quoting Apple documentation in [App Thinning](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html)

> Bitcode is the default, but optional. For watchOS and tvOS apps,
>   bitcode is required. If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks
>   in the app bundle (all targets in the project) need to include bitcode

I am currently integrating those fundamental libraries with Carthage.

**Problem**

In order to have a clean build process, I tried to submit some pull requests to the respective owners for enabling the bitcode but, due to the complexity of their codebases, which are working for multiple operating systems/architectures, my pull requests are still in pending: so, to be able to build my own project, I still have to change manually their build settings.

**Question**

How can I short-circuit the Carthage process for injecting specific build settings (in this case `ENABLE_BITCODE = YES`) into the relevant libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution by making a shell script able to erase the disabling of bitcode, in case someone is facing or curious to solve a similar problem, the script is this:

```sh
carthage update --platform ios
for D in ./Carthage/Checkouts/*; do
  if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
    find $D -type d -name \*.xcodeproj -print0 |
      while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' folder; do
        sed -i '' 's/ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;//g' $folder/project.pbxproj
      done
    fi
done
carthage build --platform ios
```

---

so basically the script's mechanism is:

1. downloading all the dependencies
2. for each dependency, find the`pbxproj` living inside `xcodeproj` and cut off the string `ENABLE_BITCODE = NO`
3. finally building the dependencies to make the .`framework`

Comment: I've asked the symmetric question for reference: [How to disable Bitcode on Carthage dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607492/how-to-disable-bitcode-on-carthage-dependencies). Maybe you know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Andrea's answer, make sure you carthage build with `--no-use-binaries` as the dependency may have a bitcode disabled in its released framework which will be used without `--no-use-binaries`.