# How to disable Bitcode on Carthage dependencies

Tags: ios, carthage, bitcode, xcode-project

How to disable Bitcode on dependencies where it's enabled?

This question is the *opposite* scenario of the question "[Bitcode disabled on Carthage dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431964/bitcode-disabled-on-carthage-dependencies)". Unfortunately, while the given answer by the OP was using a nice trick by **stripping all instances** of `ENABLE_BITCODE = NO;` in the project file, it's inapplicable to **add** that line where it's missing.

Comment: @BenjaminBojko thank you, I've made it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have an xcconfig file for carthage to add build properties when building the frameworks.

```
XCODE_XCCONFIG_FILE="myConfigFile.xcconfig" carthage bootstrap --platform iOS
```

2. Where myConfigFile.xcconfig would disable bitcode:

```
ENABLE_BITCODE[sdk=iphoneos*] = NO
```

Credit [Brennan Taylor](https://github.com/brennantaylor) on https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/2440.

Thanks to [Benjamin Bojko](/users/782899/benjamin-bojko) for the link.